# Text labels for a plot

Tags: r

I would like to use this plot:

```
    dtf1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1:10),text = c("my", "and","keep","any","somenone",
"exist","tr",
"ggplot2","euf","edff"), 
Diff = c(-5:4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I tried this:
Error in f(..., self = self) : Breaks and labels are different lengths
Which will include the text of text column as labels in every respective bar.

```
    dtf1$colour <- ifelse(dtf1$Diff < 0, "firebrick1","steelblue")
    dtf1$hjust <- ifelse(dtf1$Diff > 0, 1.3, -0.3)
    dtf1$colour <- ifelse(dtf1$Diff < 0, "negative","positive")
    ggplot(dtf1,aes(ID,Diff,label="",hjust=hjust))+
         geom_bar(stat="identity",position="identity",aes(fill = colour))+
         scale_fill_manual(values=c(positive="firebrick1",
negative="steelblue")) + 
scale_y_continuous(labels = dtf1$text) + 
coord_flip()
```

And the error is

:

> Error in f(..., self = self) : Breaks and labels are different lengths

Comment: `geom_text(aes(label=dtf1$text))`

Answer (score 1):

Just like one of the comments suggested:

```r
library(ggplot2)
dtf1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1:10),text = c("my", "and","keep","any","somenone",
                                         "exist","tr",
                                         "ggplot2","euf","edff"), 
                   Diff = c(-5:4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dtf1$colour <- ifelse(dtf1$Diff < 0, "firebrick1","steelblue")
dtf1$hjust <- ifelse(dtf1$Diff > 0, 1.3, -0.3)
dtf1$colour <- ifelse(dtf1$Diff < 0, "negative","positive")
ggplot(dtf1,aes(ID,Diff,label="",hjust=hjust))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="identity",aes(fill = colour))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(positive="firebrick1",
                             negative="steelblue")) + 
  scale_y_continuous() + 
  geom_text(aes(label=text)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It's essentially the same thing as above except we use `geom_label` instead if you'd prefer.

```
ggplot(dtf1,aes(ID,Diff,label="",hjust=hjust))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="identity",aes(fill = colour))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(positive="firebrick1",
                             negative="steelblue"))+
  geom_label(aes(label=text))+
  coord_flip()
```